# Delphi Thread timing

Tags: multithreading, performance, delphi, pascal, multitasking

I am trying to evaluate the speed of simultaneous threads. I don't understand the result. It's like there is a lock somewherer. I am running the following on a Dell 3571, 20 core/thread i9:

1. unit Unit1;

   ```
   interface

   uses
     Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
     Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

   type
     TMyThread = class(TTHread)
     public
       procedure Execute; override;
     end;

     TForm1 = class(TForm)
       Memo1: TMemo;
       procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
     private
       { Private declarations }
     public
       { Public declarations }
       procedure Log(Sender: TMyThread; Log: string);
     end;

   var
     Form1: TForm1;

   implementation

   {$R *.dfm}

   procedure TForm1.Log(Sender: TMyThread; Log: string);
   begin
     Memo1.Lines.add(Log);
   end;

   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   var
     Thr: array[0..19] of TMyThread;
   begin
     for var t := 0 to 10 do
     begin
       var Thread := TMyThread.Create(True);
       Thr[t] := Thread;
       Thread.Priority := TPHigher;
     end;
     for var t := 0 to 10 do
       Thr[t].Resume;
     end;

   { MyThread }

   procedure TMyThread.Execute;
   begin
     sleep(500);
     try
       var ii: nativeint;
       var Start := GetTickCount;
       for var i := 0 to  750000000 do
           inc(ii);
       var Delta := (GetTickCount - Start);
        Synchronize( procedure begin Form1.Log(Self, Format( 'Done Loading : %dms', [Delta]) ); end );
       except
         asm nop; end;
       end;
   end;

   end.
   ```

While running this with 1 thread, I am getting : 320 ms for one calculation
While runing this with 10 theand, I am getting :

```
Done Loading : 344ms 
Done Loading : 375ms 
Done Loading : 391ms 
Done Loading : 422ms
Done Loading : 438ms
Done Loading : 469ms
Done Loading : 469ms
Done Loading : 469ms
Done Loading : 516ms
Done loading : 531ms
```

Should all the results be almaost the same at 320 ms ?

PS: I have tried with windows CreatThread, ITask... same result whatever the number of thread...

Any Idea? thank you.

Comment: you should init ``ii``, e.g. with 0. Otherwise you could randomly run into an overflow event in the ``for``-loop

Comment: What processor model do you have? I predict that the issue is that you don't have 10 performance cores.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that your output doesn't match your code. Your code runs 11 threads, but your output is for just 10.

Comment: Adding to memo gets progressively slower as it fills up

Comment: @marco that's not relevant here, is it

Comment: I do see the listed times increasing by 50%, but that could also be due to lowering of the frequency on an all core workload.

Answer (score 3):

You are spinning up 10 threads (in addition to the main thread running the application), but you are not telling Windows anything about scheduling them other than setting the priority to "Higher".  All that can be determined by that "higher" thread priority is that your 10 threads all have the same priority when the Windows scheduler comes to allocate timeslice on a CPU/core.

Unless told otherwise, the scheduler will look at many factors to determine which core/CPU to schedule any thread on at any given point in time.

As a result, each thread could find itself being switched from one core to another on each timeslice, incurring a relatively expensive "context switch" each time.  Or it may be scheduled on the same core it is already on.  Threads that are consistently scheduled on the same core will perform "better" than any threads doing the same work with the overhead of numerous context switches.

To ensure that threads consistently run on the same core, avoiding potentially costly context switching, you need to set the Processor Affinity of each thread.  This is accomplished using [SetThreadAffinityMask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask)

### But It's More Complicated Than That

In addition, on modern CPUs there may be a mix of higher performance vs higher efficiency (typically slower) cores, so again depending on which core a particular thread is scheduled on at any given moment, it may be running "faster" or "slower" than other threads (though the OS should be ensuring that the most demanding threads are scheduled onto higher performance cores, this cannot be relied on as there are other factors).

Whilst you can contrive to schedule each thread on a separate, consistent core, what you can't do (so easily) is also determine what else Windows decides to schedule on each core, so there will still be some variability in performance between threads performing ostensibly the same work, depending on what the core they are assigned to is also doing.

If you are embarking on a project intended to extract maximum performance from a system via threading on a range of different hardware configurations (dual/quad/hexa/octa/more-core systems), be aware that the ideal configuration of your threads *will* vary across those different configurations.

This is particularly true when you develop real workloads to be performed by your threads rather than synthetic metrics-gathering workloads.  If those workloads are periodically blocked by I/O they may be better off running on efficiency cores, or running on performance cores for CPU-bound work then re-scheduling onto efficiency cores when in an I/O wait-state (if you have that mix in a given workload).  This is precisely the job that the OS scheduler will do for you (or try to).

If necessary, you will either need to devise heuristic techniques to adapt the configuration dynamically or provide some mechanism for the software to be manually configured to "tune" performance (or both).

Or, don't worry about it; accept that such variability is unavoidable and allow the OS to do the best job it can and only worry about stepping in to "do a better job" via configuration if it actually proves necessary.

Comment: There is another reason for OP results. And that is the fact that he is running his program on a 12 gen Intel Core i9-12900H processor which has 8 Efficient-cores and 6 Performance-cores with hyper-threading support) essentially giving 12 high performance cores. So running same code on a Performance-core instead of Efficient-core will make huge difference.

Comment: PS: Since OP set same priority to all of the threads it is possible that Windows scheduler spread the load across Performance and Efficient cores in a way that actually balanced the performance difference between them and thus giving less performance difference between different threads. I bet performance difference between Performance and Efficient cores is a lot higher that can be seen in the OP results.

Comment: @SilverWarior There's only 6 performance cores. Two threads per core doesn't give you 2x scaling.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I'm aware of the fact that Hyper-Threading doesn't double the performance and that running code on a virtual core will generally be always slower than running same code on a actual physical core. But on modern CPU's performance penalty for running code on Virtual core would be a lot smaller than running same code on an Efficient core.

Comment: "To ensure that threads consistently run on the same core, avoiding potentially costly context switching, you need to set the Processor Affinity of each thread. This is accomplished using SetThreadAffinityMask" I don't believe that this is true. The scheduler will attempt to run threads on the processor that they were most recently running on. I would fully expect anybody following your advice here to make their program worse.

Comment: @SilverWarior "But on modern CPU's performance penalty for running code on Virtual core would be a lot smaller than running same code on an Efficient core." It depends on the code. In my program with classic symmetric hardware, virtual cores offer nothing and it's more efficient just to disable hyperthreading. Efficient cores are very slow too! Btw, I hadn't read your comments here before I wrote my comment to the Q, and it's obvious that the answer is performance vs efficient cores.

Comment: Setting the thread affinity on the perf core does not solve the problem. It is twice slower... (1 thread being 600ms)

Comment: @LaurentMeyer That's to be expected, because setting thread affinity is very poor advice. Please please tell us what your processor model is, and read about performance vs efficient cores.

Comment: :@ David :) ...

Comment: As for possible gains or drawbacks of setting Processor Affinity for individual threads. If your application is the only one that is setting specific Procesor Affinity for its threads it can be very beneficial as it avoids context switching between different cores. But if there are more applications setting same Processor Affinity to their threads as you do to yours then you are forcing your thread into sharing processing power with another application thread on a certain core while there might be other cores sitting at idle.

Comment: @SilverWarior Even with just one program setting affinity, there may be other programs running and manual affinity setting will impact performance. And imagine you wrote a program that set affinity before efficient cores were introduced? I categorically disagree with you and Deltics on this matter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Check my first comment for information about OP processor model. I already checked the mode in order to get information about the number of cores OP procesor has.

Comment: @SilverWarior That Dell computer can be supplied with many different processors. Why can't we have the processor model in the question? I mean, it's the processor model that is driving everything we can see here.

Comment: I9 12900H - 64GB

Comment: @LaurentMeyer Not in the comment thread. Please edit the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "I would fully expect anybody following your advice here to make their program worse.".  Yes, in some cases that will be the result, hence the need to provide configuration.  I have worked on complex multi-threaded systems where *very* fine-grained "tuning" was required to extract the required performance from the overall system, specifically a real-time simulation with very specific time-slice budgets for individual workloads.  The optimum config varied unpredictably from CPU to CPU but in all cases was necessary as the OS scheduler didn't yield the desired performance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan BUT in the vast majority of cases, extracting every cycle of performance out of a system usually isn't a concern.

Comment: In this case what you are suggesting though will make the performance worse for the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: What I "suggested" was that some form of configuration would be *required* to *ensure* that best performance was obtained.  I'm not sure how a mechanism that ensures optimum performance tuning could be said to make performance "worse" for anyone, let alone the "majority of cases".  otoh if *OP* is just looking for *consistent* results and doesn't care about performance, then even if it makes performance worse, the *OP* - by definition - doesn't care.  The OP is just one case, not a "majority of cases".  I credit people with brains enough to figure out what applies to/is best for them.

Answer (score 2):

Your processor is the [i9 12900H](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/sku/132214/intel-core-i912900h-processor-24m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz/specifications.html). This has 6 performance cores, and 8 efficient cores. The performance cores are fast at the cost of power consumption, the efficient cores are slower, but consume much less power.

So this means that you do not have a symmetric set of processors. Although Intel might like you to think that you have 20 processors, you actually only have 6 fast processors. So I predict that if you changed your program to run 6 threads you would get results closer to your expectation.

Even accounting for all of this, you still cannot always expect linear scaling in a real world application. Your code is an artificial test, and the inner loop can be implemented entirely using registers. But with real world applications you can expect code to use main memory. And then in order to achieve linear scaling you depend on the memory system to deliver data to the processors efficiently. Whether this can be achieved depends on interplay with the program and the hardware.

Comment: There is a spread of results (aside from 3 identical ones which are neither the fastest nor slowest).  If the core efficiency/performance were the only (or even dominant) factor, would we not expect to at least see two more distinct groups of results?  i.e. "fast" threads vs "efficient" ones.

Comment: @Deltics Well, no, because once the performance cores have finished their jobs, they can pick up the part done jobs that were running on the efficient cores. This could easily be demonstrated by pinning each job to a specific core. But you'd need a machine with perf & eff cores

Comment: @Deltics I also think that there could be some interplay with 2 cores per thread. The performance cores have hyperthreading, the efficient cores don't. This processor has 6 perf, 8 eff. So 6*2 + 8 = 20. If you run the original code on a symmetric machine, with as many threads as physical cores, then each thread takes the same amount of time.

Comment: Yep, without threads tied to specific cores it is literally impossible to know what's going on.  I guess in a nutshell: "it's complicated".  Affining threads to cores may simplify things in order to aid understanding, but isn't necessarily the best "solution" to whatever "problem" the OP sees here.